# Как остановить поток при вводе команды?

Tags: python, многопоточность, telebot, бот

```
def start_parser(message):
    if db.get_temp_country(message.from_user.id) == 'pool':
        pool = PoolUi()
        thread_counter = Thread(target=pool.generate_link).start()
        thread_counter = Thread(target=loading_advs(message).start()
```

У меня есть функция в телеграмv боте, которая запускает парсер из другого класса "PoolUi", соовместно с ним запускается другая функция, которая показывает процесс загрузки. Как сделать чтобы в при вводе команды "/stop" парсер завершался, а бот мог дальше работать?

Answer (score 0):

Если воркер блокирующий, то `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc`.

Если воркер обрабатывает циклы, то на каждой итерации проверяй переменную и делай `break`, если переменная выставлена командой стоп.